# What does "a chip of strawberries" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, british-english

In Chapter 10 of *Ulysses*, there is another confusing quote among all the other innumerable "poetic" and "literary" and "metaphorical" ones:

> Blazes Boylan walked here and there in new tan shoes about the fruitsmelling shop, lifting fruits, young juicy crinkled and plump red tomatoes, sniffing smells.
>
> H. E. L. Y.’S filed before him, tallwhitehatted, past Tangier lane, plodding towards their goal.
>
> He turned suddenly from ***a chip of strawberries***, drew a gold watch from his fob and held it at its chain’s length.

(Italics mine)

What does "a chip of strawberries" mean in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The OED has the definition for *chip*:

> Chiefly British. A small basket of a type used for packaging fruit. Cf. chip basket,

and for *chip basket* they have

> chip basket  n. a small, light basket made of thin flexible strips or shavings of wood woven or joined together and typically used for collecting or packing fruit and vegetables; now frequently historical.

Comment: Oh yeah, those things. Now they're all made out of single use plastic because humans suck.

Comment: You also see *punnet* (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/punnet#:~:text=a%20small%20box%20or%20basket%20that%20soft%20fruit%20is%20often%20sold%20in).

Comment: @Mazura - wood ones are still available, although they may cost more. You just need to shop somewhere charging you extra for things that are compostable, plastic-free and/or artisanal-looking

Comment: A chip is noticeably bigger than a punnet, the expectation would be that a customer would not buy the whole lot at once https://www.basketryandbeyond.org.uk/farmingtamar-valley-chip-baskets-2/ last photo 'Picking box to hold two chips or eight punnets.'

Comment: @Useless Yes, though I don't use the term 'chip basket' in the US, when reading the description it instantly brought to mind the small wooden baskets that I commonly encounter here at farmer's markets.

Comment: I'm English, and moderately well-read, and I had never heard, and didn't recognise, this sense of "chip".

Answer (score 3):

"Fig. 81. Chip Baskets of Strawberries" from *The Fruit Grower's Guide* (1891) by John Wright.

[image: illustration of a rectangular basket with a handle filled with strawberries]

Comment: Welcome M. V.  Lovely illustration, the image would benefit from a text description for accessibility.